# Creating PKCS#12 keystore with multiple certificates using OpenSSL 1.0.0a

Tags: import, certificate, openssl, pkcs#12

I am trying to create a PKCS#12 keystore with more than one certificate. this option does seem to be documented well - everyone talks about creating a .p12 file from a single certicate in a .pem file, like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my_single_signed_cert.pem -out keystore.p12 -name "Alias1"
```

this creates a new .p12 file each time. If you try to create 1 keystore with 2 certificates like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my_signed_cert.pem -out keystore.p12 -name "Alias1"
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my_other_signed_cert.pem -out keystore.p12 -name "Alias2"
```

the keystore.p12 file contains only "Alias2".

I have to use PKCS#12 (enterprise toolset requires it), and I know JKS can import certs just fine.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see to ways to do this:

1)Create PEM file with all certificates you need

2)Use -certfile option to define more certificates